Extract raster subset from another one using OSGeo OGR Geometry in Python
IMPORTANT! Please note I don't want to use shapely, rasterio, geopandas or any other level of abstraction there is.

I have generated multiple polygons such as these:

For every polygon (in the picture: small, no transparent ones) I have created a larger one (in the picture: big, transparent ones) that describe the surrounding area, which I need to process in some way.
The small polygons are loaded from GeoJSON files, which I have created on a random basis, while the big ones are created using an envelope that wraps around a circle with center as the centroid of each small polygon and a radius of a specific constant size.
Note: The big polygons are simply OGR Geometry instances so not really a full fledged Features.
I am looking for a way to use those big polygons to extract the underlying raster data (GeoTIFF) as NumPy array using OSGeo (I presume I will need GDAL and OGR) in Python. Assume that all of the data is in the same CRS.
The large raster is already loaded in memory. Given the number of polygons that I will be working with (thousands if not more) it would be best not to have to load it for every polygon just to clip it since this would be very inefficient.
I tried following the tutorials on Raster API and Warp API, which I was told I need to check out but I am at a loss perhaps due to lack of in-depth knowledge in GIS topics.

UPDATE 1:
Based on the answer from @user2856 I managed to get this for my first large polygon:

As you can see the location is ok, but raster data is just black. I tried gdal.Translate() with both my already opened raster as well as just passing the file's name as the data source. Both led to the same result.
UPDATE 2:
Ok, I had to adjust the gdal.Translate(). Apparently something weird happens with the output parameter. Note that I have multiple rasters on top of each other so I had to remove one in order to post a proper screenshot here:

The only issue is that the extracted raster subset appears to be darker in some areas:
No fancy visualization

With large polygon

With loaded raster subset


Extract how?  To a numpy array?  If your polygons are always rectangular and in the same projection as the raster then you can simply use Band.ReadAsArray(), or Dataset.ReadAsArray()

I forgot to mention NumPy. Added to the question

I have added some more note to the post incl. how I load the small polygons and create the large ones. @mikewatt So I basically need to read from...to of my raster? But would there be a need for some sort of a transform since I am not starting from the top left corner but rather have very specific locations withing the raster's local coordinate system?

This has reminded me why I moved to using rasterio and geopandas... :) But I understand that sometimes you have to work with what's available.
You can use gdal.OpenEx to open your vector data, then loop through each feature and use GetEnvelope to get each geometry extent which you can then use to subset the raster with gdal.Translate
from osgeo import gdal

inshp = "rect.shp"
shpid = "A_FIELD_NAME"  # A field in the shapefile to identify each feature (integer or short string field only)
outtif = "clip_{shpid}.tif"  # will result in clip_A.tif, clip_B.tif etc...
intif = "raster.tif"

ds = gdal.OpenEx(inshp, gdal.OF_VECTOR)
lyr = ds.GetLayer(0)

for feat in lyr:
    featid = feat.GetField(feat.GetFieldIndex(shpid))
    geom = feat.geometry()
    minx, maxx, miny, maxy = geom.GetEnvelope()
    gdal.Translate(
        outtif.format(shpid=featid), 
        intif, 
        projWin=[minx, maxy, maxx, miny], 
        creationOptions={"TILED": "YES", "COMPRESS": "DEFLATE"}
    )

Input:

First output:

Addressing the edited question to output numpy arrays:
inshp = "rect.shp"
intif = "raster.tif"

inshp_ds = gdal.OpenEx(inshp, gdal.OF_VECTOR)
lyr = inshp_ds.GetLayer(0)

intif_ds = gdal.OpenEx(intif)
inv_gt = gdal.InvGeoTransform(intif_ds.GetGeoTransform())

for feat in lyr:
    geom = feat.geometry()

    minx, maxx, miny, maxy = geom.GetEnvelope()
    minpx, minpy = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(inv_gt, minx, maxy)  # maxy becomes minpy as rasters are georeferenced bottom up and arrays are top down
    maxpx, maxpy = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(inv_gt, maxx, miny)

    minpx, maxpy = math.floor(minpx), math.ceil(maxpy)
    maxpx, minpy = math.ceil(maxpx), math.floor(minpy)

    cols = maxpx - minpx
    rows = maxpy - minpy

    array = intif_ds.ReadAsArray(minpx, minpy, cols, rows)



I added more information in my post. I create the large polygons as plane OGR Geometry instances so no shape file to read from. So I guess I have to skip all but up to the point where you call the gdal.Translate(). My large polygons are also already created as bounding boxes (check the info about the invisible circles).

Also currently it would be best not to save the raster subset as a file but rather store it as a NumPy array since I need to process it as such anyway and this would be an extra IO operations (extract raster subset, store as file, load as file, process raster subset).

Thanks. One more thing (I fixed it myself) - you assume that I'm using a shape file but I am creating the ogr.Geometry myself. So the GeoTransformation is retrieved from the raster itself. If the resulting NumPy array is to be written again as a raster to GeoTIFF file (e.g. to debug the step), an additional transformation needs to take place, namely replacing of the upper left x (index 0 of the geotransform) and upper left y (index 3 of the geotransform) in the GetGeoTransform() so that raster subset is aligned with the envelope that was used for extracting it in the first place.

As for the "would have been better ..." - I have just started learning all this so this information did not pop into my head until I read the comments and your answer. Sorry about that.
